# What does wasm3 on v8 meaning on wasm3’s benchmark

Tags: v8, webassembly

On WASM3‘s Performance Benchmark

https://github.com/wasm3/wasm3/blob/main/docs/Performance.md

Under the Fibonacci Test, there is an entry called
wasm3 on V8 (Emscripten 1.38, node v13.0.1)

What does that even meaning here

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: wasm3 is a C program (that just so happens to be a Wasm interpreter), and as such can be compiled to Wasm and then executed on a Wasm engine. For example, wasm3-compiled-to-Wasm could be run on wasm3-compiled-to-native. Or it could be run on V8.

Whether compiling a Wasm interpreter to Wasm and running it on another Wasm engine is ever *useful* (for anything other than demonstrating that it's possible) is a different question :-)

If you want to know for sure, you should probably ask this question on the wasm3 issue tracker.

Comment: Ty. I should definitely try wasm3's github issue tracker. I was also thinking that it meant porting wasm3 outputs to v8 but I was not sure how emscripten was involved. I will let you know if they answer me on github